# Time of disconnection in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

In Ubuntu server (with ssh protocol), how I can change the time of disconnection for inactivity?

Answer (score 2):

If, perhaps you want the other way around (disconnecting inactive clients from the server), the respective options are `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ClientAliveInterval`, located in `sshd_config`.

Use `man 5 sshd_config` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and set appropriate values for `ServerAliveCountMax` and `ServerAliveInterval`.

From `man ssh_config`:

> ServerAliveCountMax
>                Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may be
>                sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the server.
>                If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are
>                being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, terminating the
>                session.  It is important to note that the use of server alive
>                messages is very different from TCPKeepAlive (below).  The server
>                alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and there‐
>                fore will not be spoofable.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by
>                TCPKeepAlive is spoofable.  The server alive mechanism is valu‐
>                able when the client or server depend on knowing when a connec‐
>                tion has become inactive.
>
> The default value is 3.  If, for example, ServerAliveInterval
>                (see below) is set to 15 and ServerAliveCountMax is left at the
>                default, if the server becomes unresponsive, ssh will disconnect
>                after approximately 45 seconds.  This option applies to protocol
>                version 2 only; in protocol version 1 there is no mechanism to
>                request a response from the server to the server alive messages,
>                so disconnection is the responsibility of the TCP stack.
>
> ServerAliveInterval
>                Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
>                been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through
>                the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The
>                default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
>                the server, or 300 if the BatchMode option is set.  This option
>                applies to protocol version 2 only.  ProtocolKeepAlives and
>                SetupTimeOut are Debian-specific compatibility aliases for this
>                option.